# Android handler for different screen sizes

Tags: java, android, libgdx, game-engine

I need to know how my game can handle all these screen sizes i have seen a few options including:

- Re sizing the elements to fit the screen
- Making assets in lots of different sizes
- I'd like to know which is more efficient ?
- What are my other options ?
- How would i go about making it work ?

So far i am just making my screen fit to the android device i'm testing on and this could lead to failure in the future if i do not set this handler up

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

well if you are using libgdx then you dont have to worry about screen sizes. just use its camera class and set its viewports accordingly . [refer this link for camera](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/Camera)

Also you dont need to make android handlers for it.

Answer (score 1):

This website talks about how to handle this problem http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html.

It claims the best practices are:

1. Use wrap_content, fill_parent, or dp units when specifying dimensions in an XML layout file
2. Do not use hard coded pixel values in your application code
3. Do not use AbsoluteLayout (it's deprecated)
4. Supply alternative bitmap drawables for different screen densities

The problem is not with the dimensions of the screen, rather the density of the screens. Using `dp` to set the size for elements is the most common way.

Comment: To add to this, pay attention to the part where you can specify different layout resource folders to hold XML files of the same name as the main layout folder. It lets you use alternate XML resources, maybe with different margins/padding to accommodate bigger or smaller screens, and also handle portrait/landscape mode.